# variable or field `commonStack' declared void

Tags: c++, class

Please help me out. I am getting the above error message but haven't been able to resolve it yet. I have pasted the header file and the commonStack function  here. Maybe you'll see something I missed. I'm also getting an "unterminated ifndef" error message. As you can see from the header file, I ended the class with endif. So I'm not sure of what I'm doing wrong. Please help. Thanks.

```
//Header file. 
//Class definition for the stack ADT

#ifndef _mystack_H
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define _mystack_H


const unsigned int maxSize = 10;

class Stack
{
  public:
            Stack(); //constructor

            ~Stack(); //Destructor

            bool isEmptyStack();

            bool isFullStack();

            void pushStack(int newItem);

            void popStack(int item);

            void initializeStack();

            void fillStack(int numSize);

            void exchangeTopAndBottom(Stack &stk);

            void printStack(Stack &stk);

            int sumStack(Stack &stk);

            void OddElem(Stack &stk);

            //void commonStack(Stack &stk1, Stack &stk2);

            void intersectStack(Stack &stk1, Stack &stk2);

   private:
            int maxSize;  //variable to store the maximum stack size
            int stackTop; //variable to poit to the top of the stack
            Stack arrList;//pointer to the array that holds the stack 
                          //elements

};      

#endif



//commonStack finds the union of two stacks
void Stack::commonStack(Stack &stk1, Stack &stk2)
{
     Stack temp, temp2, tempStk, tempStk1, tempStk2, cStack;
     int elem, elem1, elem2, elem3;

     while (!stk1.isEmptyStack())
     {
       stk1.popStack(elem);
       cStack.pushStack(elem);
       tempStk1.pushStack(elem);
     }

 while (!stk2.isEmptyStack())
 {
       stk2.popStack(elem1);

       while (!tempStk1.isEmptyStack())
       {
             tempStk1.popStack(elem2);

             if (elem1 == elem2)
             {
                       temp.pushStack(elem2);
                       tempStk2.pushStack(elem2);
             }
             else
             {
                 temp2.pushStack(elem2);
                 tempStk2.pushStack(elem2);
             }
       }

       while (!tempStk2.isEmptyStack())
       {
             tempStk2.popStack(elem2);
             tempStk1.pushStack(elem);
       }

       tempStk.pushStack(elem1);
}

 while (!cStack.isEmptyStack())
 {
       temp2.popStack(elem3);
       cStack.pushStack(elem3);
 }

 printStack(cStack);
}
```

Comment: `commonStack` is commented out and there is no `#endif` in the code you posted.

Comment: @curiousguy: Yes there is, is just not at the end of the file.

Comment: I see `#endif`. But where is the declaration of `commonStack`?

Answer (score 1):

You define `commonStack` but never declare it in the `class` (the declaration is commented out). Also, that's not the usual way to use header guards, its usually done like this:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_GUARD_H
#define MY_HEADER_GUARD_H

... code for the header file here, ALL code ...

#endif
```

Change the macro definition to something that does not start with an underscore, as those identifiers are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: As K-Ballo pointed out:
(1) commonStack is commented out in class
(2) your include guards are off (though I 'm not sure if leading underscores in macro is a big deal, I know it is for symbols due to linker behavior

Additionally commonStack hash semantics of a member function ... but that does not make sense.
If commonStack is a member , it should either be defined as a stand-along function (maybe a friend of Stack) or perhaps a s a member function that compares self to another.

Comment: I forgot to uncomment commonStack. I commented it out when I began to get the error message. What do you mean by a stand-a-lone function or friend of Stack? Could you give me an example? This is my very first class project so I'm not familiar with all the terminology. Thanks